# When I use a function `store.dispatch` in axios,the browser reported an error "Maximum update depth exceeded"

Tags: reactjs

When i use the funciton store.dispatch to change the isTokenTimeout in store,
the browser report the follow error：

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

- api/index.js

```sh
import {store} from '../../redux/index';
axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
        return response;
    },
    error => {
        store.dispatch({type:'CHANGETIMEOUT'})
        if (error.response) {
            switch (error.response.status) {
                case 401:
                    // fakeAuth.signout();
                    // history.push('/login');
                    break;
                default:
            }
            const message = error.response.data.message ?error.response.data.message :"服务器异常";
            Message.error(message);
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

- PrivateRoute file

```sh
import React from 'react';
import {Route,Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {fakeAuth} from '../util/fakeAuth';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
const PrivateRoute = ({component:Component,...rest})=>{
        return (
            <Route
                {...rest}
                render = {props => (fakeAuth.authenticate() && !rest.isTokenTimeout)?(<Component {...props}/>):(
                    <Redirect to={{
                        pathname:"/login",
                        state:{from:props.location}
                    }}/>
                )}
            ></Route>
        )

}
function mapStateToProps(state){
    console.log(state);
    return {
        isTokenTimeout:state.isTokenTimeout
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```